# difference between state separately and together in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, state

I write state In the form of

```
 const [state,setState] =useState({
    type:false,
    imageSrc:'',
    captionImage:'',
    showImage:false,
});
```

when change state in the form of

```
setState({type:true});
setState({captionImage:'hellooo'});
setState({imageSrc:link});
```

and send it to another component, there is undefined in that component,
but I write state In the form of

```
const [type, setType] = useState(false);
const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState('');
const [captionImage, setCaptionImage] = useState(false);
const [showImage, setShowImage] = useState(false);
```

when change state in the form of

```
setType(true);
```

and send it to another component, there is ok in that component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in the first form, when you are setting the new state instead of passing a new full object like this:

```
{
    type:false,
    imageSrc:'',
    captionImage:'',
    showImage:false,
}
```

You are setting your state to this:

```
{type:true}
```

The other props are gone, if you want to replace only one prop in your state (for example `type`, while keeping the other ones, you would do something like this:

```
setState({ ...state, type: 'new value' })
```

Comment: What you said is true and it works but the value of the state does not change in the other component, the initial value is

Comment: @zahraei and how are u passing down the props?

Comment: @ Marcos => passing the props In the form of:
 {
     state.showImage ? <ShowImage                                                               
       imageSrc={state.imageSrc}                    
     caption={state.captionImage}                                                                                
     type={state.type}                                                                                                    
      />
       : ''"
}